# Is nozzle no longer heating up correctly related to hotend insulation being pulled off?

Tags: hotend, abs, tevo-tornado

The insulation of the heater block got pulled off...

I was trying to print ABS on my TEVO Tornado, overnight. But I not-so-smartly left the window open overnight, thinking it was alright (as to remove the fumes) but then it warped so much that it pulled off the insulation of the hotend.

It is no longer heating up to over 200 degrees Celcius. It starts showing a message saying `PRINTER HALTED: PLEASE RESET` Should I just re-insulate it? if I should, what do I use for insulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I had this same problem myself.

You will need to re-insulate it using a silicone block and next time don't leave the window open while printing. Just keep the fan or AC on to circulate the air.

Comment: the printer halted error could be caused by thermal runaway

Comment: And it would be a good idea to do the PID tuning for the hotend after changing the insulation.